# LitElement How to monitor the child dom and change styling

Tags: javascript, web-component, lit-element

So I have a custom element and I need to update it's styles based on a change to it's child content. For instance:

```
<my-element>
  <!-- When child content here changes I want to update styling --!>
</my-element>
```

How would I monitor the DOM changes to child content in my element? For instance, lets say if the child content contained the string anywhere with "hello" in it, then I would change the custom element styling:

```
<my-element>
  <span>Hello in <b>advance</b>!!!</span>
</my-element>
```

Normally I would use a mutation observer here and scan the dom when changes occured, not sure how to do this correctly with lit-element

Thanks in advance!

UPDATE

So I did hack together a solution using a mutation observer. Thoughts?

```
firstUpdated() {
              var shadow = this.shadowRoot;
              var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
                  mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
                      console.log(mutation);
                  });
              });

// configuration of the observer:
              var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true, subtree: true }

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
              observer.observe(shadow, config);
          }
```

Comment: Have you tried using the [slot change](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSlotElement/slotchange_event) event?

Answer (score 0):

You generally shouldn't do something like that. If the DOM change was caused by an observed property change, then you can just do whatever changes you need in the render function. If it's not an observed change then you can call requestUpdate to force a render.